# Work with Database using Spock and Geb.

Tags: database, oracle, groovy, spock, geb

I hope someone have already faced an issue to verify that application shows correct data from database. I reviewd how groovy used SQL, but I have no idea where and how I should do that. I'm just starting to use gradle+Spock+Geb for testing application. I have a few files where I described a couple of pages from application, a couple of modules and a file with spock specification. Where and how I need to connect to Oracle DB, use SQL and compare result's data with application's ones? 
P.S. I write everything in notepad++ and launch from command line writing 'gradlew firefoxTest'. Does exist any more comfortable way to work with gradle+spock+geb?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to find a way?

Comment: Unfortunately, we parted ways before I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Because there are no other answers, I wanted to provide a solution someone at my company thought of. This assumes you already have a project that uses some sort of JDBC. In our case it is JDBI.

The idea is to extend Classloader and then use that to directly access the data access object class via the JVM. That idea should work.

I have not tested it out because it doesn't completely fit our use-case. I'll admit that this does not completely apply to your use case, but technically you could just run the jar of an existing project, which can access the database.